Prevent certain edges from being scaled
I am trying to build a road network for a game. I can already generate the texctured roads with curves and geometry nodes. Now I am trying to find a good workflow for the intersections.
I have a basic shape for the intersection(s). My idea is to put this beween the road ends which run into the intersection, and 'only' have to adjust the intersection to fit the road ends with the least amount of manual work possible (or even better, automate this).

One issue I am having is the borders of the intersection (selected in the image). This is where I put the road markings when texturing, and so I need to make sure that these always stay the same, so that the lines do not get distorted. Is there a way to fix the width of these borders (= the short edges of the selected faces), while keeping it possible to still deform or scale the rest of the intersection shape to fit different incoming roads?

The second image shows where the other road ends would run into the intersection. They can have different widths or angles but they will also have the same seam/borders in order to have a continued road marking.
This is only the start. Next level would be adding pavements or other road sides. And also there, the road sides would need to keep their width when deforming in order to match the ones of the roads which I want to connect them with.
I am trying to find a workflow where I don't have to rebuild everything manually for each intersection.
Ideally, the suggested solution would also work with geometry nodes, because I will try to automate this.
Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Same in what way? Do you need to just keep the bevel? Why not use bevel modifier instead of geometry in the mesh itself?

You could use geometry nodes for this, but it is unclear how you deform the mesh and so what solution is helpful.

You could use the Lineart modifier in Grease pencil, if the selected areas have to represent just outlines.

@MarkusvonBroady Geometry Nodes sounds interesting, but I have no idea how they could help here.

Please show us some example deformations and explain the context in which you will be using them, because there isn't a general-purpose magical solution here.

I reworded the question completely and gave more explanations, so I hope this helps to point me in the right direction. :-) Thanks already so far.

From my experience, and I think most people here will agree, the correct approach here is not to frivolously deform the mesh and then hope for some general purpose "length fixer". Instead you need to be smart about how you deform. For example here I deform by rotating the edges around a pivot point, and also inner loops around their bottoms. Then (bottom) I'm merging it all and applying subdivision surface for that 2nd derivative smoothness.

The algorithm is still imperfect, but you need to ask yourself some questions on the logic of connections, which is not Blender related but just a design problem. The way I approach such things is manually model various configurations and then figure out what's the general principle behind them...

Could you explain a bit more what the image shows? To me, right and left look the same, and top and bottom are only different because of the subdivision. I don't get the point yet...
But I do get that I should maybe think about it in a different way.

Doesn't it show the deformation you want to create? If not, that proves your question isn't very clear...
